# Where is iPhone 7Plus Depth effect flag

Tags: swift, avfoundation

When i look at my photos in my iPhone library, I can see a label called "Depth effect". This is for photos which are take in portrait mode on iPhone 7 Plus.

How the iPhone Photo app can know if this photo has the depth effect or not. I have looked in exit fields and in PHAssetResource and i have found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the EXIF data not accessible through a dict extracted from the picture?I speculate that if you get that dict there is a 'depth effect' tag somewhere. Sorry to be so vague, haven't done EXIF and Images in a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PHAssetCollection` class have a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phassetcollection/1618544-fetchassetcollections) method to retrieve asset collections of the specified type and subtype.

```
class func fetchAssetCollections(with type: PHAssetCollectionType, 
                         subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype, 
                         options: PHFetchOptions?) -> PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection>
```

which has a parameter `subtype`and it is enum of [`PHAssetCollectionSubtype`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phassetcollectionsubtype)

and `PHAssetCollectionSubtype` has a constant `smartAlbumDepthEffect` to know whether it is a depth effect photo or not.

> A smart album that groups all images captured using the Depth Effect
>   camera mode on compatible devices.